# How to get specific json elements into an array so they don't repeat?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

My problem in javascript is that I want specific elements in this case location.name to be thrown into change / array so that they don't repeat [Las "Żółta Górka", Park Wodziczki Poznań, Sala SP 5, Rzeszów].

My json api https://apidemo.outrainer.pl/firms/1/trainings?future=14&past=7

```
fetch(API_URL)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((trainingsData) => {
        trainings = trainingsData.map((training) => {
            return {
                name: training.name,
                startDate: training.startDate,
                endDate: training.endDate,
                location: training.location.name,
                type: training.location.type
            };
        });
       renderTrainingsList(trainings);

});

const renderTrainingsList = (trainings) => {
    trainings.forEach(training => {
        createTrainingsItemElement(training)
    })
}
```

I tried to render the entire array from json and throw only location.name into a separate array and at the same time they did not repeat

Comment: Basically you want to filter the items with unique `location.name` values right?

Comment: Yes, I want to download non-repeating items

Comment: You could use a `Set`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Set` to store unique location names and then filter the items.

```js
const filterItems = () => {
    const uniqueLocation = new Set();
    const trainings = data.filter(training => {
        let locationName = training.location.name;
        if(!uniqueLocation.has(locationName)) {
            uniqueLocation.add(locationName);
            return {
                name: training.name,
                startDate: training.startDate,
                endDate: training.endDate,
                location: locationName,
                type: training.location.type
            }
        }
    });
    return trainings;
}
```

Comment: How to combine it with json?

Comment: Why are you returning an object? The return value of the filter callback is ignored except for testing whether it's truthy. If you want to rearrange the data after filtering, use `map()`

Comment: I updated the code in the question

Comment: In function renderTrainingList returing

Answer (score 0):

Throw the name into the array. Then before rendering it, check whether the name is already in the array.

```js
const renderTrainingsList = (trainings) => {
  const trainingNames = [];
  trainings.forEach(training => {
    if (!trainingNames.includes(training.name)) {
      trainingNames.push(training.name);
      createTrainingsItemElement(training);
    }
  });
  console.log(trainingNames);
}
```